# Change css row in tableView javafx

Tags: css, javafx

I have a TableView with a on column contains a article and an other column with a price. I would like to change the row's css of a index row when I click in a button. 
I have this :

```
articleTable.setRowFactory(param -> new TableRow<LigneTicket>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(LigneTicket paramT, boolean empty) {

            super.updateItem(paramT, empty);
            if (!isEmpty() && paramT != null && paramT.getArticle().isArticleAnnuler()) {
                getStyleClass().add("articleCanceled");
                articleTable.refresh();
            }
        }
    });
```

But this code work on change of my tableView, not just on the click in a button, and it's not working in a index row choose.

Help please,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try use one hack after your event:

```
for ( Column col : articleTable.getColumns() ) {
    col.setVisible( false );
    col.setVisible( true );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is not a 1:1 relation between table items and table rows.

`TableRow`s only exist for visible items and may be reassigned a value. You therefore need to take care properly removing the style class.

Furthermore instead of using a style class to mark the rows, I recommend using a pseudoclass, which allows easier adding/removing.

You could store the data about the state of the item in the item class itself or store it in a suitable external datastructre.

The following example adds/removes the `removed` pseudoclass to/from table rows when the value associated with the item in a `ObservableMap` changes.

The buttons allow assigning or clearing the pseudoclass from the selected rows.

You could do a similar thing with indices instead of items too.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<Item> tableView = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Item("a"),
            new Item("b"),
            new Item("c"),
            new Item("d"),
            new Item("e"),
            new Item("f")
    ));
    tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

    ObservableMap<Item, Boolean> removed = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
    PseudoClass removedPseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("removed");

    tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<Item> result = new TableRow<>();

        ObjectBinding<Boolean> binding = Bindings.valueAt(removed, result.itemProperty());
        binding.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> result.pseudoClassStateChanged(removedPseudoClass, newValue != null && newValue));

        return result;
    });

    TableColumn<Item, String> column = new TableColumn<>("value");
    column.setCellValueFactory(td -> td.getValue().valueProperty());
    tableView.getColumns().add(column);

    Button btn = new Button("remove");
    Button btn2 = new Button("add");

    btn.setOnAction(evt -> {
        for (Item item : tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
            removed.put(item, Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnAction(evt -> {
        for (Item item : tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
            removed.remove(item);
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(10, tableView, btn, btn2));
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

```
public class Item {

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String value) {
        this.value.set(value);
    }

    private final StringProperty value = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public String getValue() {
        return value.get();
    }

    public void setValue(String val) {
        value.set(val);
    }

    public StringProperty valueProperty() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

**style.css**

```css
.table-row-cell:filled {
    -fx-background-color: lime;
}

.table-row-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-selection-bar;
}

.table-row-cell:filled:removed {
    -fx-background-color: orange;
}

.table-row-cell:filled:removed:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-selection-bar;
}
```